# How to plot a 2 dimensional function using data stored in a file with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, type-2-dimension

Is there any way to compute a 2 dimensional function using data from a file in gnuplot. Suppose I have a function `f(x,y)` which exist and I want to calculate the new values with data stored in file data.dat

i.e something like

```
plot f(x,y) using 'data.dat'$1:'data.dat'$2
```

Comment: Can you clarify what a data file looks like (a few lines of the file perhaps) and what you want gnuplot to do? For me it's not clear if you want to plot something, or if you want to obtain parameters for a function.

Comment: Perhaps you need something like: splot 'mydata.txt' using 1:2:(f($1,$2))

Comment: yep just got it a few minutes ago - thanks

Comment: @brm Please add that as an answer, so the question can be closed as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The command `plot` is used for plotting one variable against another. If you want to plot a third value against two others (and obtain something that looks 3D), you'll need the `splot` command. In this case, the command would look like

```
splot 'mydata.txt' using 1:2:(f($1,$2))
```

The `using` keyword specifies what you want to plot based on the contents of a file. The 1 and 2 means that the x and y coordinates will just be the first and second column in the file. For the third coordinate we want the f(x,y) function to be used with the values from the first and second column filled in ($1 and $2).

In case we're doing something more complex than just using a column unmodified, we have to use brackets and a $-sign for the variables. So we also could have written

```
splot 'mydata.txt' using ($1):($2):(f($1,$2))
```

as the command. See the [gnuplot manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-13400034.1.9) for more information.

Comment: @user3142307 If this answer solved your problem, please accept the question and upvote. Thats how stackoverflow works, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers